# iPod Touch 1st Gen charging rebooting loop

Tags: ipod-touch, battery, charging

I have a 1st Generation iPod touch.  When I try to charge it, it goes into a loop:

1. The very low battery logo displays
2. The black screen with white apple logo is displayed
3. The screen shuts down
4. And repeat..

Is the battery totally knackered, or is there anything else I could try?

Answer (score 1):

This loop only happened when plugged into my MacBook Pro. When I plugged into a mains charger, it successfully booted to the OS... Weird.